Can we decide the existence of some regular language closed under a Thue system?
Given a regular language $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ and a finitely presented Thue system $R$ in a finitely extended alphabet $\Sigma' \supseteq \Sigma$, can we decide whether there is a regular language $L' \subseteq \Sigma'^*$ that is closed under $R$, and $L' \cap \Sigma^* = L$? I tried to reduce the halting problem or the string rewriting problem to it, but did not come up with a method.

Thanks, I've updated my problem; I meant to consider Thue systems. The word problem asks whether $u$ can be transformed to $v$, but here I want to ask (decide) whether this problem is regular.

So you might be able to reduce a word problem $(u,v)$ in a Thue system over the alphabet $\Sigma'\setminus\Sigma$ to your problem. Probably by taking $L={a}$, and extending the rewriting relation by $(a, u)$ and $(v,b)$, or something like that

If I take $L={a}$, $R={(ba, a)}$, then there is no such $X$ because it must be the case $ba \in L \cup X$, which is impossible. But we can take $L'={b^* a}$

Right. So the rephrasing doesn't work. That doesn't seem to impact the reduction idea though

The problem is (always) that the congruence class of $a$, no matter it includes $v$ or not, appears to be complex (and not regular), if the word problem $(u, v)$ is undecidable.

Here's another random guess: reduce the problem "Given a computable function $f:\mathbb{N} \to{T,F}$, does there exist $n$ such that $f(n)=T$?" instead. We can a priori turn such a function into a Thue system whose runs start from $a$, then computes successive values of $f$ untils it gets a $T$ output (i.e. $a \rightarrow_R^* \overline{0} \rightarrow_R^* f(0)\overline{1} \rightarrow_R^* f(0)f(1)\overline{2} \rightarrow_R^* f(0)f(1)...f(n)\overline{n}=F...FT\overline{n}$, where the overline represents some encoding from $\mathbb{N}$ into words) and then keeps adding $F$ on the left of the $T$

, with the possibility of erasing the $\overline{n}$ at each of these intermediate steps. The intersection of the congruence class of $a$ with ${T,F}^*$ is $F^T$ when $f$ is a positive instance, and $F^$ when it is a negative one. We might be able to ensure that the congruence class of $a$ is regular for positive instances $f$ because the run until the first $T$ is finite, and the behavior of then adding $F$s is regular.

The problem is undecidable, already for very particular cases.
This is because in the case $\Sigma'=\Sigma$, the problem is equivalent to deciding whethe
r a given rational subset of a monoid $M$ is recognizable. Here, $M$ is the monoid
$\Sigma^*/R$, i.e. the monoid presented by the equations in $R$. This is also called the "
recognizability problem" for $M$.
Recognizability is decidable for some monoids (e.g. finitely generated commutative monoids), but in many cases, it is undecidable. As an example, if $\Sigma=\{a,b,c\}$ and $R$ allows us to commute $a$ with $b$ and $a$ with $c$ (i.e. $R$ contains the two rules $(ab,ba)$ and $(ac,ca)$), then $M$ is the trace monoid whose commutation relation is a path on three nodes. As shown by Sakarovitch [1], it is undecidable whether a given rational subset of $M$ is recognizable. (In fact, Sakarovitch characterizes all trace monoids in which recognizability is decidable.)
[1] J. Sakarovitch, The 'last' decision problem for rational trace languages, LATIN'92,
https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0023848

I’m confused. It seems to me that given a regular language $L\subseteq{a,b,c}^*$ (say, as a DFA $A$), it is decidable whether $L$ is closed under ${(ab,ba),(ac,ca)}$ (construct an NFA $A'$ that works as $A$, except that it may nondeterministically decide to exchange some $a$ with a later symbol, and test whether $A$ and $A'$ recognize the same language). What am I doing wrong?

Also, I may be confused by the terminology (unfamiliar to me), but I do not understand how you got to the problem whether “a given rational subset of a monoid $M$ is recognizable”. The problem for $\Sigma=\Sigma'$ is, given a regular language $L$ and a Thue system $R$, decide if $L$ is closed under $R$. In terms of the monoid $M=\Sigma^/R$, and going by the definitions in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recognizable_set this says, ”given a presentation of $M$ and a rational subset of $\Sigma^$, decide if it is recognized by $M$”. So $M$ is the target rather than source of the homomorphism.

Ah, you're right! My argument is flawed, thank you! But I think with a slight modification, one can still reduce the recognizability problem (in the case of $\Sigma$ being strictly smaller than $\Sigma'$---if they're the same, you're right, the problem is decidable). What's the right thing to do, edit my answer, or delete and post a new one?

Come think of it, the algorithm in my first comment is perfectly general: it shows that the problem for $\Sigma=\Sigma'$ is decidable.

It seems we posted comments at the same time. It is definitely preferable if you fix your existing answer rather than post a new one.
